# Kendo MVC Grid Default Sort by Multiple Column Fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

```html
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<...>()
  .Columns(columns =>
  {
    columns.Bound(j => j.Type);
    columns.Bound(j => j.Code);
  })
  .Sortable(s => s.Enabled(true))
  .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Sort(p => { p.Add("Code").Ascending(); p.Add("Type").Ascending(); })
    .Model(model => model.Id(j => j.ID))
    .Read(...)
    .ServerOperation(true)
  )
)
```

I have a Kendo MVC Grid as above and want to sort it first by `type`, then by `code`.

I have found such implementation on official Telerik forum:  [Default Grid Sorting](http://www.telerik.com/forums/default-multi-sort-on-grid-)

However it seems it fails to work...

[image]

The records are sorted by two columns, and apparently it is sorted by `Type`, but it fails to sort by `Code` afterwards...As *Default* should after *CG*...

What am I missing and how can I fix the problem?

Comment: Does anyone have a solution for this? I'm experiencing the same issue..

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for a solution, using the model property names worked for me, i.e.

```
       .Sort(s =>
       {
           s.Add("Code").Ascending();
           s.Add("Type").Ascending();
       })
```

Comment: Oddly, vs2019 won't even let me type in this format of code. When I put in  the semi-colon, it automatically moved it outside the sort method to the end of the whole block of code.

Comment: How is this different from the original code in question which does not work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
.Sort(p=> {p.Add(s=>s.Code).Ascending(); p.Add(s=>s.Type).Ascending();})
```

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I tried this way, but it is not working, it results in the same ordering in the grid